# Regression with constrained coeffcient Using SAS

Tags: sas

How can i fix some coefficient of my model and estimate the others ?
The way to make it using `Stata` is to write the following function:

For instance:

```
Test (VAR 1=0.5) (Var 2=1), Coef
```

Comment: Why does your question have the [tag:r] tag?

Comment: For R, look at `offset`, it can be used fix the known coefficients.

Comment: Thks, But could u please write an example for that... ?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion regarding the use of Stata commands. `test` is used to "Test linear hypotheses after estimation". To add a linear constraint for model estimation, you can use `constraint`.

Comment: I would remove the Stata and R tags and edit out the erroneous Stata syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume you are looking to do this in SAS.

In PROC REG, use the restrict statement to fix a coefficient.

```
proc reg data=sashelp.cars;

   /*Fit unrestricted*/
   model msrp = horsepower weight;
run;

/*Fit restricted*/
   model msrp = horsepower weight;
   restrict horsepower=250;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: thank u DomPazz 
This statement works perfectly :)